# Reading list of values from text file into MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, file-io, text-files

I have a text file containing two column data, separated by a comma. However, the first 10 lines contain information which I do not need.

The input text file looks as follows:

```matlab
# PROGRAM NAME                                      
# The first 10 lines are info I don't need        
#                                           
#                                                                                 
#  
#

892
5
564
1, 0.4377E-014
2, 0.0673E+000
...
```

I am trying to write a code which reads the value pairs starting on Line 11 into a 2 column matrix.

My (failed) attempt thus far is as follows:

```matlab
fin = fopen(fullfile(cd, file_name), 'r');
tLine = fgets(fin);
while ischar(tLine)
    crit_list = [crit_list; tLine(:)];
end
```

My intention was to delete the first 10 lines of the matrix after the code had executed, and then use `str2num` on the value pairs, but I'm not sure this would be very efficient.

How can I read this file into MATLAB, starting from the 11th line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`importdata`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) has the ability to skip header lines:

```
importdata(file_name,delimiter,10);  % skip 10 header lines
```

where you have to specify your delimeter, judging the file you'll want `delimiter = ','`, i.e. a comma.

Comment: Is there a faster way to do this though? I see the program takes over a second to execute for a test list of just 120 values, when I would like to read much larger files...

Comment: @najusten the time is long because opening a file takes time (your program talks to the OS and waits to get it read). Its likely that 1200 values just take 5% more time. Try it first.